How to optimize the output of a large number of characters on the console?
I am developing a program that plays video in the console using ascii characters.
This is an example of such a program text
To calculate the correct characters, I use opencl for parallelization.
Here is the code:
            MediaType::Video(video) => {
                let fps = video.get(opencv::videoio::CAP_PROP_FPS).unwrap_or(30.0);
                let ms_per_frame = (1000.0f64 / fps).floor() as u64;
                let mut frame_index = 0;

                let chars = crate::ascii::CHARS1;
                let mut size = 0;


                let mut chars_buffer = unsafe { Buffer::<cl_uchar>::create(&self.context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, chars.len(), ptr::null_mut()).unwrap() };
                let mut output_buffer = unsafe { Buffer::<cl_uchar>::create(&self.context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 1, ptr::null_mut()).unwrap() };
                let mut frame_buffer = unsafe { Buffer::<cl_uchar>::create(&self.context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 1, ptr::null_mut()).unwrap() };

                let chars_buffer_write_event = unsafe { self.queue.enqueue_write_buffer(&mut chars_buffer, CL_NON_BLOCKING, 0, chars.as_bytes(), &[]) };

                let char_len: cl_uint = 1;
                let grayscale: cl_uint = 1;
                let step: cl_uint = (255.0 / (chars.chars().count() as f32)).ceil() as u32;

                let now = SystemTime::now();
                loop {
                    let mut frame = Mat::default();
                    let result = video.read(&mut frame);
                    if result.is_err() || !result.unwrap() || frame.empty() {
                        break;
                    }

                    let terminal_size = termion::terminal_size().unwrap();
                    let new_size = Size::new(terminal_size.0 as i32, terminal_size.1 as i32);
                    
                    let mut resized_frame = Mat::default();
                    let result = imgproc::resize(&frame, &mut resized_frame, new_size, 0.0, 0.0, imgproc::INTER_LINEAR);
                    if result.is_err() || resized_frame.empty() {
                        break;
                    }

                    if grayscale == 1 {
                        let mut gray_frame = Mat::default();
                        let result = imgproc::cvt_color(&resized_frame, &mut gray_frame, imgproc::COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
                        if result.is_err() || gray_frame.empty() {
                            break;
                        }

                        resized_frame = gray_frame; 
                    }

                    let frame_bytes = resized_frame.data_bytes().unwrap();
                    if size != frame_bytes.len() {
                        size = frame_bytes.len();
                        frame_buffer = unsafe { Buffer::<cl_uchar>::create(&self.context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size, ptr::null_mut()).unwrap() };
                        output_buffer = unsafe { Buffer::<cl_uchar>::create(&self.context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, size, ptr::null_mut()).unwrap() };
                    }
                    
                    let _ = unsafe { self.queue.enqueue_write_buffer(&mut frame_buffer, CL_BLOCKING, 0, resized_frame.data_bytes().unwrap(), &[]) };

                    let execute = unsafe {
                        ExecuteKernel::new(&self.kernel)
                            .set_arg(&frame_buffer)
                            .set_arg(&chars_buffer)
                            .set_arg(&char_len)
                            .set_arg(&grayscale)
                            .set_arg(&step)
                            .set_arg(&output_buffer)
                            .set_event_wait_list(&[chars_buffer_write_event.as_ref().unwrap().get()])
                            .set_global_work_size(size)
                            .enqueue_nd_range(&self.queue).unwrap()
                    };

                    let mut string: Vec<cl_uchar> = vec![0; size];
                    let _ = unsafe { self.queue.enqueue_read_buffer(&output_buffer, CL_BLOCKING, 0, &mut string, &[execute.get()]).unwrap() };

                    let mut rgb = Vec::new();
                    if grayscale == 0 {
                        rgb = frame_bytes.to_vec();
                    }

                    self.media_sender.send(StringInfo {string, rgb}).unwrap(); 

                    let time = now.elapsed();
                    if time.is_err() {
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    let time = time.unwrap();
                    frame_index += 1;
                    let deadtime_to_frame_preparing = Duration::from_millis(ms_per_frame * frame_index); 
                    if time < deadtime_to_frame_preparing {
                        sleep(deadtime_to_frame_preparing - time);
                        continue;
                    }

                    let frames_to_skip = (time - deadtime_to_frame_preparing).div_duration_f64(Duration::from_millis(ms_per_frame)).ceil() as u64;
                    frame_index += frames_to_skip;

                    {
                        let mut skipped = Mat::default();
                        for _ in 0..frames_to_skip {
                            if !video.read(&mut skipped).unwrap_or(false) || skipped.empty() {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



__inline void write(__global uchar* output, __global uchar* input, uint output_start_index, uint input_start_index, uint len) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        output[output_start_index + i] = input[input_start_index + i];
    }
}

__kernel void calculate(__global uchar* frame, __global uchar* chars, uint char_len, uint grayscale, uint step, __global uchar* out) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    int brightness = frame[index];

    if (!grayscale) {
        brightness = (frame[index * 3] + frame[index * 3 + 1] + frame[index * 3 + 2]) / 3;
    }

    int char_index = brightness / step - 1;
    write(out, chars, index + char_len, char_index + char_len, char_len);


The code is a bit incomplete, but it works.
And everything works fine, but after 10-15 seconds of playback, the program freezes and the CPU usage increases to 100%. It can end up with the whole system freezing.
I don't understand what this can be due to, because when I used the CPU for calculations, there were no such problems. Perhaps I am using opencl incorrectly.
How can I fix the freezing problem?
And one more question, my program uses relatively few resources during operation - 15-20% of my processor, but the console (I have kitty) uses 60-70%, can I optimize it? Maybe reduce the number of frames per second or something else
My processor is Ryzen 5 5600
And GPU is GeForce 1060

You enqueue enqueue enqueue the OpenCL kernels but never finish/empty the queue. The queue blows up, fills the entire RAM and then the system freezes. So add a clFinish in every iteration.
But using OpenCL here is totally overkill. The bottleneck is how fast you can dump characters into the console. As for which characters to choose: create a lookup table at initialization, then you don't need to compute the character selection every frame.
The key here is to minimize the amount of printed characters: for grayscale it's trivial (just one buffer of W*H characters). For color, you need ASCII escape sequences to change color, and there you can combine blocks of characters of the same color, to have only one color change in between. With dithering you get more than the 16 standard colors.
To optimize even further, you can keep the last frame (as ASCII) in memory, compare the new frame with the last, and only reprint the changed characters.
With all these optimizations, full color video is feasible, see here.

I've tried add finish, but i still have a freezing.
self.queue.finish().unwrap();
also i've tried
self.queue.flush().unwrap();
self.queue.finish().unwrap();

